# Criar um objeto em Java pelo usuário usando Scanner ou JOptionPane

Tags: java

Geralmente quando se cria um objeto nós digitamos Classe obj1 = new Classe();
Mas e se eu quiser que o usuário crie de forma interativa no console e dê um nome (igual esse obj1) ao objeto, como se faz?

Comment: Esse tipo d metaprogramação não é possível em Java, mas provavelmente deve existir alguma outra abordagem para fazer o que você está tentando fazer. Você poderia por exemplo criar um `HashMap<String, Classe>` e utilizar o que o usuário digitou como índice do seu objeto.

Comment: E em que parte o HashMap torna-se interativo na criação de objetos?

Comment: O HashMap permite que o usuário defina o nome da "variável". Se a interatividade que você quer é permitir que o usuário digite a linha de código completa, aí não tem como fazer em Java mesmo, precisaria de alguma linguagem de alto nível que suporta `eval`.